# Threads in JDK 1.8

Tags: multithreading, java-8

We have a Multithreaded application that was working fine in jdk 1.7. After we upgraded to Jdk 1.8, one of our threads stopped working as expected. The call method for this thread is at the bottom of this post/question.

It seems like the thread stays in runnable state and is not selected by the JVM to run for some reason. However if we uncomment "The Statement" in the below code everything works. My assumption is that without this line the JVM thinks that the thread is not doing anything and therefore does not select this thread to run. Is this true? What can we do to solve this besides placing dummy code to print something.

```
public String call() {
    String result = "";
    try {

        while (!SomeClass.singleton.isDone()) {
            //The Statement - Everything works if you uncomment below statement
            //System.out.println("Status : " + elapsed);
            elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 60000;

            // check the max job run time.
            if (elapsed > SomeClassProperties.singleton().getMaxRunTime()) {
                System.out.println("MaxRunTime exceeded.  Killing job.");
                SomeClass.singleton.killJob();
            }

            // don't log status until we've discovered the payload count
            if (SomeClass.singleton.getPayloadsFound() < 1)
                continue;

            System.out.println("Status : " + elapsed);

            logErrorMessages();

            Thread.sleep(30000);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the declaration for elapsed look like? what happens if you make it an AtomicLong?

Comment: long elapsed = 0L;

Comment: Is `SomeClass.singleton` published safely? Are the singleton's methods properly synchronized? If not, the JIT might be doing something unexpected. What does a thread dump show? That is, what is the thread's stack trace?

Comment: This looks like a typical problem of code that is not thread safe. Inserting a print statement makes it working as a side effect of the `PrintStream`’s internal synchronization. Of course, relying an that side effect is not a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I miss my guess, your thread goes into a heavy non-switching endless loop due to the while condition being true, and the if-condition before "continue" staying false.

The System.out implicitly yields the thread, therefore your other threads have a chance to get some cpu time.

Thus, try inserting

```
Thread.yield()
```

or

```
Thread.sleep(someSmallTimeInterval)
```

in your if-continue block.